# Owner cannot remove a 'Developer' member from the Group Projects Individually in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I gave access to a developer to a group with 'Developer' Permissions. When I go to the members of a project under the group, I cannot remove that 'Developer' member individually. This is only happening for one member. All other users with 'Developer' permission can be removed. How can I remove the individual member from group projects?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That was reported two years ago in [gitlab-org/gitlab-foss issue 33129](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/33129)

> 1. Create a new repository in a group as an owner. (All group members will be added automatically as members of this repo)
> 2. Try to delete one of the members at `https://gitlab.com/<name_of_the_group>/<name_of_the_project>/settings/members`

This is linked to [gitlab-org/gitlab issue 33534](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/33534)

> Implement an option on the group settings page, available only to group Owners, that allows a user to disable forced member inheritance from parent groups.
>
> When enabled, all inherited members should be removed from group access and the membership of the group must be defined specifically for that group.

This is still in study and might be for GitLab 13.0 (May 2020)

Comment: An option for the owner to override the permissions of the added users would be great. Now, I just removed them from the group and added them individually. Is there any other option for this?

Comment: @JintoAntony I don't see another option at the moment.